# Google Script Собрать даты из определенной колонки и проверить на просрочку

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Суть в чем. Есть книга из 12 листов. На каждом листе даты начала и конца. Необходимо чтобы скрипт проходил по всем листам(это нашел как сделать) собирал данные из нужной колонки(G) (хотя там могут быть по мимо даты пустые значения и текст) и в случае обнаружения хотя бы одной просроченной даты отправлял письмо на заданную почту.

Пока все что смог написать:

```
function checkDate() {


  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  for (var sheet of sheets) {
    var column = sheet.getRange('G:G');
    var values = column.getValues();
     
  GmailApp.sendEmail(me, 'Необходимо обновить даты', ssPersonal.getUrl());

  
  
  }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простая линейная компоновка отчета из Таблицы:

```js
const intl = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ru-RU', {
  dateStyle: 'short',
  timeStyle: 'short',
});

function checkDates() {
  const book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = book.getSheets();
  const now = new Date();
  const report = sheets.reduce((acc, sheet) => {
    const sheetName = sheet.getName();
    const sheetGid = sheet.getSheetId();
    const data = sheet
      .getRange('D:D')
      .getValues()
      .reduce((ac, row, i) => {
        if (row[0] && row[0].getTime && row[0] <= now) {
          const item = {
            row: i + 1,
            sheetName,
            date: row[0],
            sheetGid,
          };
          ac.push(item);
        }
        return ac;
      }, []);
    acc.push(...data);
    return acc;
  }, []);

  const url = book.getUrl();
  const reportHtml = report
    .map(
      (item) =>
        `<div>
        <a href="${url}#gid=${item.sheetGid}&range=${item.row}:${item.row}">Лист '${item.sheetName}'/ строка ${
          item.row
        }</a>
        : ${intl.format(item.date)}</div>`
    )
    .join('');

  console.log(reportHtml);
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: 'hire@contributor.pw',
    htmlBody: reportHtml,
    subject: `Отчет от ${intl.format(now)}`,
  });
}
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не учтен фильтр листов и многие другие полезные вещи.